# Use Infimum Lemma to prove that there are $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ such that $d=|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and define
$$d=\inf\{|x-y|:x\in A \text{ and }y\in B\}$$
Use Infimum Lemma to prove that there are $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ such that $d=|x-y|$

I would really appreciate some hints and suggestions on how to go about proving this. Please, no full proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Since A and B are compact sets in R, they are both closed and bounded.   Now, what **is** the "infimum lemma"?

Comment: If d is a lower bound for the set, then d is the infimum if for every epsilon >0, there exists an element, |x-y|, in the set such that d+epsilon> |x-y|.
Okay, so how does that help necessarily?

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\epsilon=\frac1n$, there exist $x_n\in A$, $y_n\in B$ such that
$$
d\le|x_n-y_n|\le d+\frac1n.
$$
Now, you know that $A$ and $B$ are compact, so...

Comment: So..... ? I actually have what you've written, as suggested by my professor, but I'm really not making the connections that I should.

Comment: It is a *very fundamental* thing about a compact set and an infinite sequence $x_n$ of its element. Check [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Yes, so every sequence contained in A or B has a convergent subsequence that converges to a limit IN A or B. I see that. Okay got it. Thank you!

Comment: At last: you take the limit for those subsequences to see that $|x_*-y_*|=d$ (the squeesed limit).

Comment: Gotcha, okay. Another quick question: How could I prove that $d$ is the limit of the sequence $(x_n-y_n)$? It makes sense that it does, and by the construction of the terms for the sequence, it clearly does. But when I try to use the definition of convergence to show for any given $\epsilon$ that $|x_n-y_n|-d|<\epsilon$, I get a bit stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned before about. If $x_n\to x_*$ and $y_n\to y_*$ then by continuity $|x_n-y_n|\to |x_*-y_*|$, and since $d\le|x_n-y_n|\le d+1/n$ we get $|x_*-y_*|=d$ by [taking the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).